# Uninstall service provider from Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I just install backpack as service provider through composer, and i need to uninstall it. its just to remove the classes form config/app and delete the folders? or how ti do it?

Comment: You don't need to remove folders, composer will do it for you. Just remove the service provider from config and run `composer remove package/name`.

Comment: i got this error laravel/backpack is not required in your composer.json and has not been removed Package "laravel/backpack" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, first you have to remove it from `config/app.php file`. Then you can do it in two ways. Just like @lado commented, do

```
composer remove package/name
```

Or remove package/name from composer.json file and do

```
composer update
```

Comment: I remove it from config/app.php then remove them from composer.josn then its remove some items but still have folders in my folder directory!

Comment: What folder you are still seeing?

Comment: `resources/views/vendor/backpack` and `vendor/backpack`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I create a service provider that was cache by application, so I can't run artisan to clear cache after remove it. IN this case just go to `bootstrap/cache` and remove cache file manually. Now you can use artisan to cache application again.